# How do I make a navbar scroll the page when clicked on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, I have a button in the navbar titled "German", and when the user clicks on "German", it scrolls down to an h2 titled "Traditional German Foods". Same thing, if a had a button in my navbar named "French", the user's page would then scroll down further to an h2 named "Traditional French Foods". I've been learning code for about 4 months now, and I can't seem to figure this out, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us some markup and what you’ve tried. Hint: use anchor links and IDs.

Comment: In the old day's, that's what anchor tags & id's were designed for.   So you can use javscript scroll, but if it's simple you just say create an anchor tag..  `<a href="#german">German</a>`   and then say on a div later in your page you have.   `<div id="german">content</div>`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is using # hashes, you put an id in your **h2** like `<h2 id="german">German</h2>` and your links from the header should be something like this:

```
<a href="#german">Jump to German</a>
```

Further info can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention, you can use id's and anchor tags. But that scrolls instantly. To easily animate the scroll, you can use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

> The [Scroll Behavior specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) has been introduced as an
>   extension of the Window interface to allow for the developer to opt in
>   to native smooth scrolling. So far, this has only been implemented in
>   Firefox.

There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) for other browsers.

## element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})

```
document
  .querySelector('YOUR_TRIGGER_HERE')
  .addEventListener('click', event => {
    document
     .querySelector('YOUR_DESTINATION_HERE')
     .scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#german">German</a>

<h2 id="german">Traditional German Foods</h2>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this code does and how to use it. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

You can do an anchor with your a tag and then it will scroll down instantly, you can use javascript to improve it.

```
<a href="index.php#german">German</a>


<div id=#german></div>
```

Comment: Your markup is a little bit confused here..   should be `href=#german` and your `id="german"`..